# Does using different ports allows for less congestion on server Apache

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, port

I have 4 different virtual host running on my server under Apache2. Until now some where listing on port 80 some on 443 and some on custom port like 434. Please disregard SSL issues here.

My question: Does dispatching client request on different ports allows for less congestion (more traffic) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.

(Filler to get up to 30 chars)

Comment: I'll take you for your word then.